# Exceptions in System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been getting two exceptions at random times in my asp.net mvc code running on iis7:

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

and

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It's not consistently reproducible, but I assume it's something changing (or corrupting) `RouteTable.Routes`.  The only place I access `RouteTable.Routes` in my project is in `Global.asax.cs` and I know that the code there is only being called once, so it's not the problem.  Any idea on how to track it down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, it ended up being a HttpModule: [Ext.Direct.Mvc](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=347906#post347906) (Ext.Direct for ASP.NET MVC). This module had a bug (Fixed in version 0.8.0) which registered routes again every time Init() was called for the IHttpModule. ([which might be called multiple times](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/10/MoreHttpModulesStrangeness.aspx)).  If the timing was right, it would corrupt the `RouteTable.Routes` collection, and cause one of the two exceptions above.

Answer (score 4):

That error is consistent with a collection not being thread-safe in .Net.

As per the MSDN article on [RouteCollection.GetWriteLock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getwritelock%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), `RouteTable.Routes` is not thread-safe. This issue is because some piece of code tried to modify the `RouteTable.Routes` in a manner which was not thread-safe.

The best practice is to modify the `RouteTable.Routes` in the `Application_Start`.  If you have to modify it in a way which can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, make sure you make it in a thread-safe way.  Check the example from MSDN, copied below for ease of reference:

```
using (RouteTable.Routes.GetWriteLock())
{
    Route newRoute = new Route("{action}/{id}", new ReportRouteHandler());
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(newRoute);
}
```

Same applies for when reading from the RouteTable - [RouteCollection.GetReadLock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getreadlock%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Probably, if this was fixed by removing the HttpModule, it is because this HttpModule does not implement such locking mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers explained WHAT happens but provided little details on **how to actually track it down**. It may not be your own code causing all this trouble, so Ctrl-F is not enough..

### The idea

What makes solving it difficult, is the fact that you usually get errors on a different requests than the ones actually modifying RouteCollection. A generally safe call to `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl()` or the like would fail at seemingly random times. To track it down, I chose to move exceptions from victims to the culprit by forbidding changing routes after the initial set up.

### Step 1: Implement custom `RouteCollection`

IF a flag is set then yell hard when someone tries to change routes. It's a crude implementation but you get the idea.

```
public class RestrictedRouteCollection : RouteCollection
{
    public Boolean EnableRestrictions { get; set; }

    protected override void InsertItem(Int32 index, RouteBase item)
    {
        if (EnableRestrictions) { throw new Exception("Unexpected route added."); }
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(Int32 index, RouteBase item)
    {
        if (EnableRestrictions) { throw new Exception("Unexpected change of RouteCollection item."); }
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(Int32 index)
    {
        if (EnableRestrictions) { throw new Exception("Unexpected removal from RouteCollection, index: " + index); }
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        if (EnableRestrictions) { throw new Exception("Unexpected clearing of routecollection."); }
        base.ClearItems();
    }
}
```

### Step 2: Replace the default collection

In Application_start in Global.asax replace the default RouteCollection with your instance before the routes are set up. As there does not seem to be an API to replace it then we force it with reflection on the private fields:

```
var routeTable = new RestrictedRouteCollection();
var field = typeof(RouteTable)
    .GetField("_instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (field == null) { throw new Exception("Expected field _instance was not found."); }
field.SetValue(null, routeTable);

Debug.Assert(RouteTable.Routes == routeTable);
```

### Step3: Restrict changes once intended routes are set up

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routeTable);
routeTable.EnableRestrictions = true;
```

**All done!** Now watch the bad request light up in exception logs.

#### A possible culprit: ImageResizer

In my case it was a 3-rd party component named `ImageResizer` (v4.0.4) whose internal `MvcRoutingShimPlugin` took the liberty of adding/removing a route without locking. This specific bug was [already reported and fixed](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/issues/228) (though at this time not yet officially released).

Comment: This comment is a real lifesaver! I ran into the same problem als the OP did. I was sure that my own code didn't modify anything about the route tables, why would i want to do that. So i was kind of in the dark on this, so I decided to use this approach. Turns out if was the ImageResizer plugin as well in my case (but it could have been something else).